# Can I release a Silverlight application to the Mac App Store?

Tags: silverlight, macos, app-store, mac-app-store

Is it possible to release a Silverlight application to the Mac App Store? I don't talk about iOS (I know this won't work) but MacOSX. Will it be rejected outright, are there technical problems to expect, do I have to bundle Silverlight with the app and so on?

Maybe someone already has tried to release an application that way and knows about the pitfalls.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mono Moonlight applications are getting accepted (http://www.mono-project.com/Moonlight) so there is a good change that yours also will. Afcourse you need to make sure that your application runs with Moonlight.

Here is how you do that: http://www.mono-project.com/MonoMacPackager#Mac_AppStore_Distribution

Comment: Thanks. So if Silverlight, Java, .Net at large or whatever runtime I can think of would be usable without an installation the application  would be approved? Did you hear about any endeavors on that matter?

Comment: Yes they would but you need to do a couple of things (dev account, some certs etc.). Here is a how-to: http://technology.blurst.com/unity-games-and-mac-app-store/ (Unity runs on Mono)

Answer (score 2):

your app will be get rejected

> 2.24 Apps that use deprecated or optionally installed technologies (e.g., Java, Rosetta) will be rejected

see this link - http://developer.apple.com/appstore/mac/resources/approval/guidelines.html

Comment: you'll need a apple developer account to view that link

Comment: Thanks for your help. Saurabh is right though, I couldn't view the page because I have no developer account.

Comment: I uploaded the pdf copy of this page here - http://hotfile.com/dl/115391687/3649e5d/Mac_App_Store_Review_Guidelines_-_App_Store_Resource_Center.pdf.html you can check

Comment: also please accept the answer if you think its right...